# Android how to call this json array ...?

Tags: android

I dont know how to call this json array in android...I have tried below array type calling but it not worked,
Suggestion plz

```
["a","b","c","d"]
```

My java

```
 JSONArray arrays = null;
JSONObject object = null;
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPostExecute(result);
String jsonResult=result;
try 
{
object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
} 
catch (JSONException e) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
arrays = new JSONArray(result);
object=arrays.getJSONObject(0);
textView.setText(object[0]+""object[1]));
```

Logcat

```
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545): Process: com.example.loading_mysql, PID: 5545
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at com.example.loading_mysql.MainActivity$JSONParser.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:100)
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at com.example.loading_mysql.MainActivity$JSONParser.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-06 09:06:40.272: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My postexecute,,,after added the code u said,,,not works stilllkgjkgkgv gdsghsadgsg

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            String value = null;
            JSONArray jr = null;
            try {
                jr = new JSONArray(result);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

                try {
                    value =jr.getString(0);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            textView.setText(value);
            }
```

Comment: "I have tried below array type calling but it worked" If it works what suggestion do you want

Comment: there is no json object in your code

Comment: What do you mean 
JSONObject object =new JSONObject(jsonResult);

Comment: `["a","b","c","d"]` i do not see a jsonobject here

Comment: ya i understand 
I know how to call this
{"name":"Froyo","version":"Android 2.2"} ...

And I dont know how to call without jsonobject.

Comment: please indicate line 100 @ MainActivity

Comment: use `value =jr.get(0);` instead of `value =jr.getString(0);` as Raghunandan said

Comment: ya got it @Shayan,,,,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a `JSONArray`. There is no `JSONObject` in the below json.

```
[
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d"
]
```

To parse

```
JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(jsonResult);
for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
{
    String value = (String) jr.get(i);
}
```

`[` represents json array node

`{` represents json object node

To clarify the question in your comment

```
{
    "name": "Froyo",
    "version": "Android 2.2"
}
```

The above is a json object

Edit:

```
@Override 
 protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    { 
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        String value = null;
        try {
             JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(result);
             value =(String) jr.get(0);
             textView.setText(value)
            } catch (JSONException e1) 
            {   
            e1.printStackTrace();
            }
     }
```

Comment: @ArunShankar if this answer helped, you should mark this as answer to help other people that has a same problem

Comment: It still throws error 

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      String value = null;
      JSONArray jr = null;
   try {
    jr = new JSONArray(result);
   } catch (JSONException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
   }
      
          try {
     value =jr.getString(0);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
      
      textView.setText(value);

Comment: @ArunShankar what is line 100??

Comment: @ArunShankar the code is fine but there is NPE at line 100 what is line 100.

Comment: value =jr.getString(0);,,,i have attached the postexecute also there.

Comment: @ArunShankar json array is null. Make sure you  result is not null. Check the response from server. The code is fine

Comment: Thank you @Raghunathan,,,, i put jr.getstring() instead of jr.get(),,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49198/discussion-between-arun-shankar-and-raghunandan)